# Create background animation like frontierwithin.thorne.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, html5-canvas

I'm looking to create the background animation just like https://frontierwithin.thorne.com/

They seem to have coded the background animation using Javascript and are spawning objects (each bubble is a separate object I guess) and animates across the screen and destroys itself.

Is it possible to create something like that using anime.js (animejs.com)? If not, could you suggest me a better alternative library?

Are there any tips of where I should begin?

In case you cannot open the website, here is how the background looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSc6d.jpg

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should try to produce something first, then ask people to help you perfect it. Come up with minimal code at least.

Comment: Of course. But I guess if someone could point me in the right direction, I could get it done. However, I don't know which library to use. I'm currently experimenting with anime.js but creating so many random particles seems to be a bit challenging.